# Program not finding any ID3 info from an MP3 file even though the specified file has ID3 info

Tags: java, file, stream, mp3, id3

I have tried specifying the direct route of the file, I have tried putting the route as the value of the File variable to no avail. The program identifies the file (because it does not output an error message) but it does not recognize it as an MP3 file with ID3 information which it does have. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ID3Reader {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        File song = new File(arguments[0]); 
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(song)) {
            int size = (int) song.length();
            file.skip(size - 128);
            byte[] last128 = new byte[128];
            file.read(last128);
            String id3 = new String(last128);
            String tag = id3.substring(0, 3);
            if (tag.equals("TAG")) {
                System.out.println("Title: " + id3.substring(3, 32));
                System.out.println("Artist: " + id3.substring(33, 62));
                System.out.println("Album: " + id3.substring(63, 91));
                System.out.println("Year: " + id3.substring(93, 97));
            } else {
                System.out.println(arguments[0] + " does not contain"
                     + " ID3 info.");
            }
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error -- " + ioe.toString());
        }
    }
}

//Output is "C:\Users\gabbs\OneDrive\Music\4 Non Blondes - What's Up.mp3 does not contain ID3 info."
```

Comment: Keep in mind that ID3v1 and ID3v2 are completely different standards.  Your ID3 reader probably only does one or the other.

Comment: "does not contain"... how about printing what `tag` contains so you have a hint of what is there actually? Maybe you're off by 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print out the string id3. There is probably just a missing CRLF or so. When you see what id3 looks like it, you can reverse engineer it.

I ran your program and had some issues reading the file. I fixed it as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = new ID3Reader().getClass().getClassLoader();

    File song = new File(classLoader.getResource(args[0]).getFile());
    try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(song)) {
        int size = (int) song.length();
        file.skip(size - 128);
        byte[] last128 = new byte[128];
        file.read(last128);
        String id3 = new String(last128);
        String tag = id3.substring(0, 3);
        System.out.println(id3);
        if (tag.equals("TAG")) {
            System.out.println("Title: " + id3.substring(3, 32));
            System.out.println("Artist: " + id3.substring(33, 62));
            System.out.println("Album: " + id3.substring(63, 91));
            System.out.println("Year: " + id3.substring(93, 97));
        } else {
            System.out.println(args[0] + " does not contain"
                    + " ID3 info.");
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error -- " + ioe.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It printed 128 U's

Comment: Please use comments in your code and avoid generics like "some issues" and instead formulate the details. Nobody knows which problem you fixed.